# Merging polygons without creating new layer

Tags: qgis, merge, splitting

I'm new to using QGIS and I ran into an issue - I would like to merge a few polygons that I created as separate. I found a way how to do it through "Dissolve" option, but this creates a new layer and I would like to keep the newly created polygon in the old layer. If that is impossible, is there a way to split polygons inside a layer into parts with distinct attributes?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about merging features, or about splitting them?

Comment: For just a few polygons, you can edit, select and merge them: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=merge#merge-selected-features

Comment: Thank you JGH - I managed to do it, however the merged polygon still doesn't show up in the attributes table, how can I incorporate it there?

Comment: Your problem is unclear.  Maybe you are confused and have different feature classes and what you want to do is copy polygons from one feature class and paste to another?  Maybe you are asking how to create multi-part geometries?  Can you post a picture of your QGIS Layers panel and highlight which layers you are working with?  Can you include a screen shot of your attribute table?

Comment: Okay, so I'm working on layer Capt_areaFeb28. - > https://ibb.co/KbKqfBy In the layer I have different polygons (as can be seen: https://ibb.co/7nvQXPj ). I would like to merge some of them (all those starting with "Chernihiv"), but so that they'd be kept in the same layer, just changing the name maybe. Hope this clears things up